# Printing 2d array in counterclockwise order

Tags: algorithm, matrix

How do you print an array in counterclockwise order? I know of the famous "print an array in spiral order" algorithm, but it'd be interesting to see how to print it in a counterclockwise fashion

Comment: Have you tried running all the looops backwards?

Comment: As in? Sorry, I'm new to programming.

Comment: what is this "famous" one you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you think of an array of 2d coordinates ...

basically you have to sort your array by the atn of the quotient of y and x coordinates and print them in order. properly catering for poles and sign changes while avoiding expensive and numerically unstable arithmetics complicates the implementation. the following pseudocode manly serves for illustratin of the principle.

the point set is partitioned into 9 categories numbered 0 to 8. #0 contains points `(0,0)` which will be printed first, #1,3,5,7 contain points on the positive y axis, negative x axis, negative y axis, and positive x axis, respectively. within each of these categories, points will be printed in order of increasing distance from the origin. categories #2,4,6,8 contain points from the second, third, fourth, and first quadrant, respectively. within each of these categories, points will be printed counterclockwise. any points located on the same vector from the origin will be printed in the order of increasing distance from the origin.

let `a:array of point(x:number,y:number)` be your array. define `f:array of (f1:number, f2:number, f3:number)` componentwise as

```
f[i].f1 :=
    let x := a[i].x, y := a[i].y;
    if x=0 then
        if y=0 then
            0
        else
            if y>0 then 1 else 5
        endif
    else
        if y=0 then
            if x>0 then 7 else 3
        else
            if x>0 and y>0 then
                8
            elsif x>0 and y<0 then
                6
            elsif x<0 and y<0 then
                4
            else
                2
            endif
        endif
    endif;

f[i].f2 :=
    let x := a[i].x, y := a[i].y, h := f[i].f1;
    if odd(h) then
        abs(x) + abs(y)
    else
        if h=0 then
            0
        elsif h=2 then
            -x/y
        elsif h=4 then
            y/x
        elsif h=6 then
            -x/y
        else
            y/x
        endif
    endif;

f[i].f3 :=
    a[i].x * a[i].x + a[i].y * a[i].y;
```

apply your favorite sorting algorithm to order `a` lexicographically ascending by `f.f1, f.f2, f.f3` and print the result in order.